# Error installing jupyterlab/jupyter notebook on MacOS big sur

Tags: python, macos, pip, jupyter-notebook, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to install jupyter on my mac, but I'm facing errors while installing.

The commands used to install:

```
pip install jupyterlab
pip install notebook
```

Both give similar errors.

I acknowledge I'm on a beta OS thus I wouldn't complain if it's not supported, just asking to make sure that it's not some stupid user-errors.

Errors shown:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting notebook
  Using cached notebook-6.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (9.5 MB)
Collecting traitlets>=4.2.1
  Using cached traitlets-5.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting prometheus-client
  Using cached prometheus_client-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting argon2-cffi
  Using cached argon2-cffi-20.1.0.tar.gz (1.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Users/yagami/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-62k24twj/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.6.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (288 lines):
  Collecting setuptools>=40.6.0
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting cffi>=1.0
    Using cached cffi-1.14.3.tar.gz (470 kB)
  Collecting pycparser
    Using cached pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: cffi
    Building wheel for cffi (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for cffi (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-install-xgpxryh0/cffi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-install-xgpxryh0/cffi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-wheel-0obo4jsw
         cwd: /private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-install-xgpxryh0/cffi/
    Complete output (130 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/pkgconfig.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
    running build_ext
    building '_cffi_backend' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/c
    xcrun -sdk macosx clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ffi -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/c/_cffi_backend.o
    In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
    #error Unsupported architecture
     ^
    In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
    typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
    typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for cffi
    Running setup.py clean for cffi
  Failed to build cffi
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, pycparser, cffi
      Running setup.py install for cffi: started
      Running setup.py install for cffi: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-install-xgpxryh0/cffi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-install-xgpxryh0/cffi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-record-09jh8alg/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-62k24twj/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-62k24twj/overlay/include/python3.8/cffi
           cwd: /private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-install-xgpxryh0/cffi/
      Complete output (130 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/pkgconfig.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/cffi
      running build_ext
      building '_cffi_backend' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/c
      xcrun -sdk macosx clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ffi -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/c/_cffi_backend.o
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
      #error Unsupported architecture
       ^
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
      typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
              ^
      Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
      typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
              ^
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
      typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
              ^
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:2:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
      In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      20 errors generated.
      error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-install-xgpxryh0/cffi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-install-xgpxryh0/cffi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-record-09jh8alg/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-62k24twj/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-62k24twj/overlay/include/python3.8/cffi Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Users/yagami/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/g0/d04hk18n311bj7rw6j_r__9h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-62k24twj/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.6.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

#### What I've tried

I've tried updating `pip` and `setuptools` but it didn't make a difference.
I've also removed the whole `/Library/Python`, still no luck.

#### Extra info

`python3 -V`:

```
Python 3.8.2
```

`pip -V`:

```
pip 20.2.3 from /Users/yagami/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

`which python3`:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

`which pip`:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

Comment: I'm not on a beta and still seeing a similar issue... were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what's going on with the built in version of python in OS X (I've heard something about compatibility switching causing unpredictable behaviour as it switches between 2 modes automatically).

Anyway, it seems installing the homebrew version of python largely skips around the issues so I suggest you go that route.

#### Install brew if not installed

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

#### Install brew version of python

```
brew install python
```

#### Add an alias to your shell (the below command is for zshell) to make python point to your new python install

```
echo "alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc
```

#### Setup a virtual environment to sequester off where you install packages to

```
python -m venv ~/.env
```

#### Activate the virtual environment

```
source ~/.env/bin/activate
```

#### Install packages to your environment

```
pip install notebook jupyter
```

Comment: I also ran into an issue `symbol '_ffi_prep_closure' not found`... building fiddle from source fixes this https://andre.arko.net/2020/06/29/symbol-_ffi_prep_closure-not-found/

Comment: Python in my machine was installed at the following path: `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`, so I had to change the following command: 

    `echo "alias python=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc`

   Tip: Look at the output of `brew install python` to see where python is installed.

Comment: For me, the important step was to use a virtual env. I first tried to install it into the main brew python, but that didn't work. In the virtual env it worked without any problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and try many things, the fastest and most effective way for me was:

```
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install
```

and then just use `pip3` for everything

Answer (score 0):

I tried each of the above answers, and I still couldn't run jupyter notebook. In case anyone else runs into this issue, after trying the above answers, I installed jupyter notebook via brew:

```
brew install jupyterlab
```

Then I was able to run jupyter notebook:

```
jupyter notebook
```