# Numpy/ Pandas/ Matplotlib taking too long to install

Tags: python, pandas

I've decided to install of MacOs Big Sur and now I do have to reinstall all the packages again... But I'm facing some problems.

I don't have much experience using terminal, but it is taking too long to install some data science libraries. For example, to install numpy it took some minutes, and right now, it's been 15 minutes since I've started to try to install the pandas lib

```
pip3 install pandas
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pandas   Using cached pandas-1.1.4.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... -
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from pandas) (1.19.4)
Collecting pytz>=2017.2
Downloading pytz-2020.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
 |████████████████████████████████| 509 kB 1.2 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pandas
Building wheel for pandas (PEP 517) ... \
```

I've been stuck at this screen for ages. 15 minutes, minimum. I can hear the fans of the computer working at full speed, also the laptop is getting warm. Why is it taking so long? Since it's only a small lib... I don't remember taking this amount of time when I installed it previously on another MacOs versions... Am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

In my case it was failing after attempting to build for like 15 20 minutes. I then upgraded pip using `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Post this the wheels were downloaded directly, and the package was installed in few seconds.

Comment: This worked like a charm on Monterey

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Pip can not find an appropriate [Pandas wheel](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files) for your platform (macOS 11.0, Python 3.8). The closest available match is for macOS 10.x. Instead, Pip needs to build the wheel (compile and link the library) before installing.

I can't say for sure without testing, but I suspect the [platform tag](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/#platform-tag) changed on Big Sur from `macosx_10_9_x86_64` to something like `macosx_11_0...`.

Until numpy/pandas maintainers release binary wheels for your platform, one option is to build them yourself.

Seems the homebrew Python doesn't suffer from this problem, so you might want to [give this a try](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64038867/).

Comment: You probably right, compatibility problems seems to be the case. I've tried to install python's  homebrew version, but I'm still having the same problem =( after 40 minutes+ I was able to install pandas, however can't seem to make other libraries such Matplotlib to work

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: (As of Oct 20, 2021) Python 3.10, released on Oct 4, 2021 is not compatible with MacOS11. Errors in build process from scratch warn that "some code will never be executed." I suspect incompatibility between xcode and clang calls. TBH, save yourself the heartbreak and go for the Anaconda/miniconda distros.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. My scenario is: MacOS Monterey, Python 3.8 and PIP 20.2.3.

My solution to this problem was just to update pip with the command:
pip install --upgrade pip.

That worked!

Comment: That's great however this answer is similar to others already given.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install numpy after installing `python-3.7.3` from Python official site, and looks like installing numpy in 3.7.3's environment is not any issue.

Answer (score -1):

Main issue seems to be Big Sur trying to protect this python3 installation it ships with. python@3.8 as is on the OS will throw these problems such as

`Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable`

I'd recommend installing another version of python3.8 with

`brew install python@3.8`

and writing a symlink to use that in the future.

`ln -s -f /usr/local/opt/python@3.8... /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: don't use `ln` for symlinking `brew` packages, use `brew link` and `brew unlink` 

see [here](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#link-ln-options-installed_formula-)